# how do i include a random page using php?

Tags: php, html

i have 20 different pages and everytime someone visits my homepage i want a random page to be displayed

my code:

```
<?php

    switch($_GET['page'])
{     
    case "1":
        $page = include('pages/1.php');
    break;
```

more cases etc. now the random part (if no specific page is called)

```
default:
    $page = include('pages/ rand(1, 20) .php');
    break;
}?>
```

i tried using rand(1, 20) but it wont work that way.
thx for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [*string concatenation*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) and **accept answers** ;)

```
include('pages/' .  rand(1, 20) . '.php');
```

Btw. I don't think `include` has any return value so there is no need to use an assignment.

---

Even better would be:

```
$pages = range(1,20);
$page = rand(1, 20);
if(array_key_exists('page', $_GET) && in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
// or $_GET['page'] >= 1 && $_GET['page'] <= 20 instead of in_array(...)
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
include('pages/' .  $page . '.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to move it from inside the string so it can be evaluated:

```
$page = include('pages/' . rand(1, 20) . '.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are all off, the function wont evaluate if it's inside a string. Try fixing your code up to resemble something like this:

```
$page = include('pages/'.rand(1, 20).'.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$page = include('pages/' . rand(1,20) . '.php');`

Answer (score 0):

A better way to avoid the long switch:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
   $page = 'pages/'.(int)$_GET['page'].'.php'; // Always sanitise user input!!!
else
   $page = 'pages/'.rand(1,20).'.php';

include $page;
```